# Are WordPress Heartbeat API 'beats' staggered or do they occur simultaneously for all users?

Tags: php, server-load, heartbeat-api

The WordPress Heartbeat API uses admin-ajax.php to run AJAX calls. If User X leaves their browser open, many calls will be made to the server, with each call happening when there is a 'beat'. Now if User Y leaves their browser open, many more calls will be made to the server, with each of these calls happening when there is a 'beat'. It's possible a large website will also have User A, User B and User C all do the same.

**My question:**

Considering lots of users might access a website simultaneously, are WordPress Heartbeat API 'beats' staggered (the 'beat' for User X happens a few seconds before the 'beat' for User Y) or does a 'beat' occur at exactly the same time for all users?

If 'beats' aren't staggered, my concern is a very heavy load on the server at the point when a 'beat' occurs.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, it is interesting though. I imagine you could do a basic test by logging into the admin area from multiple browsers/computers and than taking a closer look at the heartbeat requests and the according PHP script executions, somewhat like mentioned in this [article](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/heartbeat-ajax-php-usage#heartbeat-in-action).

Comment: @ialocin I activated a tick logger few days ago to check this out, but I then forgot to turn it off so when I checked it out today, the amount of ticks was quite scary ;-)

Comment: I can imagine that they accumulating quickly. The example from you answer gives a good idea I guess.. @birgire

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would think the beats are *Staggered* by nature, becasue the next *tick* is determined by the  browser time `time()` within the  `scheduleNextTick()` method in the `/wp-includes/js/heartbeat.js`file:

```
 var delta = time() - settings.lastTick,
     interval = settings.mainInterval;
```

where it's used to schedule the next tick with the `setTimeout` function:

```
if ( delta < interval ) {
    settings.beatTimer = window.setTimeout(
        function() {
            connect();
        },
        interval - delta
     );
} else {
    connect();
}
```

The browser time is defined as:

```
function time() {
   return (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

The `connect()` method contains the ajax call and uses `always()`

```
.always( function() {
    settings.connecting = false;
    scheduleNextTick();
})
```

to schedule the next tick.

The available tick intervals are 5s, 15s, 30s and 60s.

For a large number of very active users, with a short tick interval, the beats might seem to happen simultaneously.

It's always good to have some data, so you could log the ticks from the logged in users, with the `heartbeat_tick` hook:

```
add_action( 'heartbeat_tick', 
    function(  $response, $screen_id  )
    {
        $file =  WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/ticks.log'; // Edit this filepath to your needs.

        if( file_exists( $file ) && is_writeable( $file ) ) 
        {
            file_put_contents( 
                $file, 
                sprintf( "%s - Tick from user_id : %d - from screen_id : %s" . PHP_EOL,
                    date( 'c' ),
                    get_current_user_id(),
                    $screen_id
                ), 
                FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX 
            );
        }
    }
, 11, 2 );
```

Here's an example from the `ticks.log` file:

```
2014-09-01T12:41:04+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : edit-post
2014-09-01T12:41:19+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : edit-post
2014-09-01T12:41:34+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : edit-post
2014-09-01T12:41:56+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:42:11+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:42:20+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 3 - from screen_id : upload
2014-09-01T12:42:38+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:43:05+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:43:08+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 3 - from screen_id : attachment
2014-09-01T12:43:20+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:43:36+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 1 - from screen_id : post
2014-09-01T12:44:17+00:00 - Tick from user_id : 3 - from screen_id : profile
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. My understanding is there are _two_ beats to a cycle. The initial beat which is determined by the browser and then a **return beat**. It's clear from your answer that the initial beat is staggered. Is the return beat (which sends data from the server back to the browser) staggered also?