# Log of Heartbeat Calls

Tags: logging, heartbeat-api

I've read that Heartbeat can slow a WP site down and I'm assuming if our admins/store managers have a lot of admin windows/tabs open, this will exacerbate the issue.

If yes, is there a condition to test and log the calls that Heartbeat makes so I can see if the site slowdown could be related to an excess of Heartbeat calls?

I had a look in the documentation and elsewhere but only found ways to deregister the script ( `wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');` ) - not what I need.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree and this is something that should be monitored via server logs, by watching: `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` ?

Comment: I remember playing with this some time ago [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159769/26350).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From quick look at the code, there is number of hooks firing in [`wp_ajax_heartbeat()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_heartbeat/). Out of which `heartbeat_tick` action seems quite appropriate to hook some logging logic too.

For the sake of completeness, while you are interested in logged in activity, the hook would be `heartbeat_nopriv_tick` for logged out users.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst - the hook does the trick. I threw together a quick function to email me everytime there was a "tick" and ran it for an hour. Amusingly, I am the worst culprit!

`add_action ( 'heartbeat_tick', 'xcsn_heartbeat_tick' );
function xcsn_heartbeat_tick ($response, $screen_id) {
 //Send an email or whatever
}`